# Show that $G'$ contains a subgroup of order $d$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, proof-verification, group-isomorphism

> Assume $G$ is **isomorphic** to $G'$ and $H$ is a subgroup of $G$ with
>   $|H|=d$.
>
> Show that there exists $H'\leq G'$ s.t. $|H'|=d$.

Let $f: G \longrightarrow G'$ be an isomorphism. Then, there exists $H' \subseteq G'$ defined as
$$
H':=\left\{ f(h), \space \forall h \in H \right\}
$$
and since $f$ is injective, $|H'|=d$. To show that $H'$ is a **subgroup** of $G'$:

$\bullet \space$ **Closure:** $\forall h_1,h_2 \in H:$
$$
h_1 \cdot h_2 \in H \iff f(h_1 \cdot h_2) \in f(H) \iff f(h_1) \cdot f(h_2) \in f(H) \iff h_1'\cdot h_2' \in H' \quad\checkmark
$$

$\bullet \space$ **Identity**: 
$$
e \in H \iff f(e) \in f(H) \iff e' \in H' \quad \checkmark
$$

$\bullet \space$ **Inverses**:
$$
h^{-1} \in H \iff f(h^{-1}) \in f(H) \iff f^{-1}(h) \in f(H) \iff h'^{-1}\in H' \quad \checkmark
$$

Therefore, there exists $H' \leq G'$ with $|H'|=d$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $f\colon G\rightarrow G'$ be a group isomorphism. By assumption such an $f$ exists. Then define $H':=f(H)$. Because $f$ is a homomorphism, $f(H)$ is a subgroup of $G'$, hence a group. Since the kernel of $f=f_{\mid H}$ is trivial, because $f$ is injective, we have
$$
H\cong H/\ker(f)\cong f(H).
$$
Hence $|H|=|H'|=d$.